# Conditional Join Statements based on Variable - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a question about altering the where statements in the where clause based on a variable flag passed in by the UI.

In the scenario there are person records in the DB and the goal is to allow the user to find duplicates based on the criteria they select. It could be any permutation of the search options to be considered duplicates.

The query is simplified for the example, but the concept is the same. Would this be able to be included conditionally in the join using IF or CASE, or would each permutation need to be its own separate query?

```
Declare @lastnamedup varchar(1) = 'N',
        @firstnamedup varchar(1) = 'N',
        @DOBdup varchar(1) = 'N',
        @SSNdup = 'N',
        @ZIPdup= 'N'

/*UI values passed could set any to Y*/

select
   p.id
   p.lastname,
   p.firstname,
   p.SSN,
   p.DOB,
   p.Address1,
   p.Address2,
   p.zip
   p.phone
from person p
join person p2 on p.id <> p2id
               and /* conditionally join based on Dup flags activated
               could be 1 or many of any of the 5 dup variables for example
               @lastnamedup = 'Y' include and p.lastname = p2.lastname*/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could do is add the joins with an or statement in which you check the value of your parameter but then you will still end up with a join. You could also build up your SQL command in a nvarchar variable (@SQL) adding the joins where needed and then perform an EXECUTE(@SQL) to get the results from the complete query.

Comment: Thanks, I think this may be the route I have to take. I am surprised this isn't a better way to handle it in SQL

Answer (score 1):

This should work assuming at least 1 value is a 'Y'. I also added datatypes to all your variables and changed them to be char(1) as varchar(1) is quite silly. Not really sure what you are trying to accomplish with this but you have what is called a triangular join (the <> predicate) which can cause really awful performance problems. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/61539/

**Also, you need stop storing SSN in clear text. It needs to be hashed with salt or at least encrypted.**

```
Declare @lastnamedup char(1) = 'N',
        @firstnamedup char(1) = 'N',
        @DOBdup char(1) = 'N',
        @SSNdup char(1) = 'N',
        @ZIPdup char(1) = 'N'

/*UI values passed could set any to Y*/

select
   p.id
   p.lastname,
   p.firstname,
   p.SSN,
   p.DOB,
   p.Address1,
   p.Address2,
   p.zip
   p.phone
from person p
join person p2 on p.id <> p2.id
    AND
    (
        (p.lastname = p2.lastname and @lastnamedup = 'Y')
        OR
        (p.firstname = p2.firstname and @firstnamedup = 'Y')
        OR
        (p.DOB = p2.DOB and @DOBdup = 'Y')
        OR
        (p.SSN = p2.SSN and @SSNdup = 'Y')
        OR
        (p.zip = p2.zip and @ZIPdup = 'Y')
    )
```

Comment: do the separate `or` clauses not have to be parenthesized individually

Comment: @daniel No, they don't. AND has higher precedence than OR in tsql: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190276.aspx

Comment: @1010 what is posted when you commented is after the fix. :)

Comment: yes, but those parentheses are unnecessary. `a AND b OR c AND d` is equivalent to  `(a AND b) OR (c AND d)`.

Comment: @1010 cool, maybe im thinking of cases where its flipped, `(A or B) AND (c OR d)`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, the ids not being equal is to prevent the same rows from matching each other. I only want the conditions met where the passed parameters are met and the ids are not the same. SSN is not clear text, like I stated above this was simplified for the example.

Comment: With the or statements if multiple Y flags are passed, will they all stack on the join? For example user picks DOBdup and lastnamedup, both should be present in the join.

Comment: If you need compound conditionals like this you will need to rethink this completely. Obviously this won't do compound conditions like that. So you are saying if Zip and DOB were both 'Y' then the join condition should only return those rows that match on both columns?

Comment: That is correct. The user can pick the criteria to perform the joins for the rows that should be considered potential duplicates, which includes multiple flags. That is why I was wondering if this could be done in a single query, or there needs to be one for each permutation.